# Dispose EntityFramework Core In-Memory Database Instance

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, mstest, ef-core-2.2

I'm using EntityFrameworkCore for unit tests and creating a new In-Memory DB instance to run the tests against. I want each test to run independently and set up the database each time, however the in-memory database instance is being shared between test methods, even through I'm creating new DbContext instances each time.

I've seen some potential solutions elsewhere online suggesting to use a uniquely named DB instance, and others which suggest overriding the service provider. I've tried both of those, but it still doesn't work.

When I run my individually, everything works. When I select multiple tests to run, the first one works and the subsequent ones fail with a duplicate primary key error.

I've pasted the relevant code below. Does anyone know how to force the database to be re-created each time?

```
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider)
        .Options;

    var dbContext = new MyDbContext(options);

    dbContext.Store.AddRange(_testStores);
    dbContext.SaveChanges(); //blows up here on subsequent tests

    return dbContext;
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not reusing `options`? I mean, since it contains in-memory database name, you're always going to get the same database.

Comment: @kalexi - yes, positive. It's an instance method which builds the context and it's called per-test - no static fields anywhere